# Solaris 11 ops center installation errors

Tags: software-installation, solaris

I am trying to install ops center on my test server but whenever I start the installation, I get:

> error: The configured Oracle Solaris 11 publisher, Solaris, does not support the version of Oracle Solaris 11 that is installed on this system.

Just tried to install local repository and my Solaris 11 knowledge is limited.

```
root@sol-blade0:~# pkg info entire
         Name: entire
      Summary: entire incorporation including Support Repository Update (Oracle Solaris 11.3.13.4.0).
  Description: This package constrains system package versions to the same
               build.  WARNING: Proper system update and correct package
               selection depend on the presence of this incorporation.
               Removing this package will result in an unsupported system.
               For more information see:
               https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=2045311.1
     Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
        State: Installed
    Publisher: solaris
      Version: 0.5.11 (Oracle Solaris 11.3.13.4.0)
Build Release: 5.11
       Branch: 0.175.3.13.0.4.0
Packaging Date: September 29, 2016 05:55:02 PM 
         Size: 5.46 kB
         FMRI: pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.13.0.4.0:20160929T175502Z
```

My Solaris 11 system version is "11.3" and ops center version is 12.3.3.1801.

Comment: Worth expanding the question to include the version of ops center you're trying to install and exactly which version of Solaris 11 you've got.

Comment: along with the above, you'll also want to provide: `pkg publisher` as well as `pkg info entire` to determine which release and SRU you may have.
I'm wondering if you don't have a valid publisher defined.